# Values in a filter disappearing after refresh

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have around 6 drop down filters in my report. In development environment they all contain values to choose:

[image]

Right after publishing the report everything looks fine as well, but if I close the report and then open it again - values in first 3 filters are blank:

[image]

Why does it happens?

In order to eliminate values in those filters I used `"Merge Query"` and 
used `Inner Join`. 
Can this effect it somehow?

[image]

Comment: An inner join certainly could cause this if you join columns that don't have matches. I can't tell what's happening from the information you've given though.

Comment: Alexis, join columns are matches. I checked to make sure. I noticed that under relationship tab CompanyLocationGuid was lower case  (dont know why) and fact_Premium was Upper. So I fixed that. 
Then microsoft support did bunch of refreshes. 
It works for now. Let's see it it will stay same way.

Comment: Update. Just checked. Now out of 3 only one filter is blank after closing and opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In query editor I formatted GUIDs columns as 'UPPERCASE' even though they were all Uppercase. 
But after I 'Close and Save' it worked.